# Reading multiple words to obtain one string file handling

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream hahaha;
    hahaha.open("input2.txt");
    char data[100];
    int blue;
    hahaha >> data;
    hahaha >> blue;

    cout << data;
    cout << endl;
    cout << blue;

    hahaha.close();
}
```

the input.txt contains "Stack Overflow 10"

This should store in variable of their own type, i.e. the "Stack Overflow" string should be stored in a char variable and 10 in an integer variable. But then only the "Stack" string is stored in the character variable and 0 in the integer variable. What should I do?

Comment: It really depends on what you need to do. You can get the whole line with getline but that'd include the 10. You could loop through the file reading one word at a time and concatenating to the buffer unless it can be converted to a number. You could switch from pure text to some other format like csv or xml. You could change the text file to have the text on one row and the number on the next. There's quite a few options depending on your needs but in this specific isolated case I'd just do a manual concatenation and then read the number.